# How do I disable error suppression "@" operator in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, error-suppression

I have a code which was written recklessly (*by previous devs ofc*) and the error suppression operator "@" was used generously all over the place. And now that I have to debug an error, it is proving a real PITA.

I have tried the regulars like setting `error_reporting` and `display_errors` but still error suppression is honoured (*maybe it is how its supposed to be*).

I have also thought of using a search and replace using `regex` but I have kept it for last resort.

Now my question is, Is there a way I can override the error suppression operator?

Comment: *Any* custom error handler would do, e.g. just `set_error_handler("var_dump");` even.

Comment: That is a great solution, mind adding that as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, This is a life saver, If you have xdebug installed there is a [flag](https://xdebug.org/docs/basic) which does exactly that, it suppresses the error suppressor :) Effectively making it easier to debug this hell of a code.

```
xdebug.scream=1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all the error suppressors and at the same time some bad practice about the abuse of the error suppressor ....

you need use your code editor and replace all `'@$'` in your code and wala you going get all error tracer... you need and not need, and go to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already had mentioned in the question that I was looking for something other than this approach, nonetheless, thanks. Btw, this approcah seems janky at best.

Comment: It seems to me that it is the best solution to quickly eliminate the bad practices inherited and start with the debugging immediately of any Warning or Error. I assure you that in the long run it will be the best way I've already passed.

Comment: suprecion error in php is embed in Compilation time cannot be configurable at this moment. The other thing you can use is the strict PHP mode `declare (strict_types = 1);`

Comment: I agree, having those error suppressions, is by itself a super bad practice, but that search and replace is super unreliable could replace comments and stuff. Hence it was last in my preferred options list.

Comment: then you must evaluate your situation before continuing, the debugging if or if you should do it manually, not by means of a script or a depreciation of a feature that is deployed in the compilation of the Apache or the engine that you have for php ... against, you can check with a "Search all" as i mention the string "@$" and check if a file is committed to a comment; replace in a comment the "@$" for a "$" should not be the biggest problem ...

Comment: `@$` is not the only use case. `@` is an operator and it could be used like `echo @(1/0)`, `$a = @b()` etc

Comment: in all cases you see the operator at begining of print, function , calc, Etc is used to suprese Warning output...

Comment: and becouse it may vary you need first make a search of '@' to avoid future problem a check previus what you need change...